# Question about this proof (Proving P^transpose * Q is orthogonal)

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

There is a true/false question that reads:
If $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal matrices then $P^TQ$ is an orthogonal matrix.

This is the given solution, which I do not understand:
$(P^TQ)^T = Q^TP = Q^{-1}P = Q^{-1}(P^T)^{-1} = (P^TQ)^{-1}$
or here is a picture so it's more readable: https://i.gyazo.com/4f66070bf4f6b5a25a4c0011e0349cc5.png

So I know that if $P$ is orthogonal then $P^T = P^{-1}$

But, right off the bat the proof starts with $(P^TQ)^T$
How can $P^TQ = (P^TQ)^T$ if the transpose of $Q$ doesn't necessarily equal $Q^T$

Can someone explain this to me?

This is an Introduction to Linear Algebra class, so please try to keep the answers as basic as you can.

Comment: You are in minor notation heck:  The transpose of $Q$ *does* necessarily equal $Q^T$ because that is what the notation $Q^T$ means.

Answer (score 1):

The book starts with the expression $(P^TQ)^T$. It does not say that $P^TQ = (P^TQ)^T$.

By definition, an orthogonal matrix  $X$ must satisfy $X^T = X^{-1}$. So to prove that $P^TQ$ is an orthogonal matrix, we must show that $(P^TQ)^T = (P^TQ)^{-1}$.

That's why the book starts with the expression $(P^TQ)^T$ and manipulates it until they get $(P^TQ)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you! But this gives 2 more questions. What motivation is there to start with $(P^TQ)^T$ and why must you prove that equals $(P^TQ)^{-1}$

What knowledge am I overlooking that suggests that $(P^TQ)^{-1}$ is what must be the end result?


edit: ohhhh nevermind I see it now!

Comment: The definition of an orthogonal matrix is a matrix $X$ such that $X^T = X^{-1}$. So to prove that $P^TQ$ is orthogonal, you need to show that $(P^TQ)^T = (P^TQ)^{-1}$. So you should start with one side, and show that it equals the other side.